# Making a multi-processor string evaluation algorithm

Tags: python, gpgpu

I have a Python algorithm that takes two strings as input and does various tests on each's characters to return a score.
This often involves 100s of pairs of strings, and since it doesn't involve writing to memory, concurrency problems shouldn't be a matter.

Thing is, from my (little) GPU programming experience, I recall it's required to make simple loops and give a fixed length to each arrays when coding for GPU (OpenGL shaders), which is annoying because strings are effectively arrays with variable array length.

I can consider turning Python strings into C-like char arrays, but it seems like a tedious solution, and doesn't solve the problem of making simple loops.

My question is this; is there any way to achieve great performance gains by parallelizing a Python code like this to GPU? Is it even possible?

```
def evaluator( baseStr, listOfStr ) :
    for word in listOfStr : # PARALLELIZE THIS
        scoreList += [ evaluateTwoWords(baseStr, word) ];

def evaluateTwoWords(baseStr, otherStr) :

    SOME WORD-WISE COMPARISON

    i = 0; j = 0;

    while i < len(baseStr) and j < len(word) :
         ...

    return someScore;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the above provided code , yes you could achieve a significant speedup  on a GPU if every thread/worker on the GPU is assigned a task to  do the string comparison.

**But there are a few constraints with a GPU.**

```
1) If the string list to be loaded into the device memory is too huge,then  
   lost of system bandwidth is utilized to copy the string list from the 
   host to device memory. This context switch is one of the biggest setbacks 
   of using a GPU

2) Also a GPU becomes very effective in solving algorithms that have a lot 
   of SIMD(Single Instruction Multiple Data) characteristics. Check  
   this out for more info on SIMD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD. So the 
   more you start deviating from  SIMD,  the more penaltiy on speedup
```

**Below is a sample Pycuda Version of your program**

I've used PyCuda but there are other OpencL python drivers that do the job as well.I haven't tested the GPU code below due to hardware constraints ,  but I've coded it primarily from these examples  http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples.

This is what the code does.

1) copy the string list to gpu device memory

2) copy the base string to device memory

3) Then call the kernel function to return something

4) Finally reduce the returned values using summation or the desired reduce 
   function of your choice

Below code is a perfect example of SIMD where the result of a thread is independent on the result of another thread. But that's just an ideal case. You might have to decide whether an algorithm can be a good candidate for a GPU or not.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

import numpy


string_list = ['Apple','Microsoft', 'Google','Facebook', 'Twitter']
string_list_lines = numpy.array( string_list, dtype=str)

#Allocalte mem  to list of strings on the GPU device
string_list_linesGPU = cuda.mem_alloc(string_list_lines.size * string_list_lines.dtype.itemsize)
#After allocation of mem,  copy it to gpu device memory
cuda.memcpy_htod(string_list_linesGPU, string_list_lines)

## ****** Now GPU device has list of strings loaded into it
## Same process applied for the base string too

baseStr = "Seagate"
baseStrGPU = cuda.mem_alloc( len(baseStr))
cuda.memcpy_htod(baseStrGPU, baseStr)

#Num of blocks
blocks = len(string_list)

#Threads per block
threadsPerBlock = 1


#Write the actual kernel function

mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ int evaluateTwoWords(char *string1, char **string2)
{
    idx = threadIdx.x;

    while len(string1) > len(string2){
        string2[i][0] = string1[0]s
        // you could probably foloow up with some kind of algorithm here 
    } 
    return len(string2)
}
""")

#Run the source model
gpusin = mod.get_function("evaluateTwoWords")
result  = 0
result += gpusin(destGPU, linesGPU, grid=(blocks,1), block=(threadsPerBlock,1,1))

return result
```

Hope this helps !